# Java AWT: Remove frame title bar and add customised title Bar

Tags: java, awt

I am new to AWT and was wondering how to remove the title bar that comes up when we open a frame and add customised title bar.

Though I was able to remove Tiltle Bar using setUndecorated(true) but not getting a idea how to add a Custom Title bar with just a ICON and Close Operartion. Also I need to color the Title Bar with a specific color.

P.S : Cannot use Swing

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: Any specific reason for not using *Swing*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 possibilities.

1. Use java.awt.Window instead of Frame.
2. Use JFrame and call `frame.setUndecorated(true);`

Comment: sorry we cant use JFrame or any swing component.. Have to aacheive it using AWT

Comment: so, use java.awt.Window. Good enough.

Comment: Hi .. But I am able to get rid of default Title using undecorated(true) but how can I add a custom Title WIndow with the description I have mentioned in my question..